# Stripe CardInputWidget not showing on the new update

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

After upgrading the stripe implementation CardInputWidget doesn't appear anymore :/

Error :
Error inflating class com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget

grandle implementation:

implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:16.9.0'

Xml code for payment dialog :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/card_outline_stripe" />

            <com.example.dev.customs.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/enter_your_payment_method"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:fontTextView="MuseoSans-900" />

            <com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
                android:id="@+id/dialogue_edit_payment_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_stripe_payment"
                android:textDirection="ltr" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:text="@string/label_submit"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gradient_blue_1"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_submit_bg"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

code:

btnStartPlan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
showPaymentDialog();}
...

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_payment);

Comment: Do you have more context? What version/API level of Android are you using? Is this on  a physical device or an emulator? Have you tried doing a fresh Gradle sync of the project?

Comment: Hello, yes i did a project clean and a rebuild.
im testing on physical devices (samsung, oppo, huawei, lge nexus 5x) 
version 8 , 9 ,10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:' to 1.3.0 or 1.4.0-alpha02
cause the CardInputWidget of stripe payment to not be inflated in the layout and cause a crash,

Updating stripe dependency to 'com.stripe:stripe-android:16.10.2' solves this issue.

I opened this issue on stripe GitHub and they worked on the fix,
for more info check this link:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/3770

happy coding.

Comment: When linking an issue like that (especially with a ton of stuff to read through), you should add a description in your answer on how exactly to fix it (e.g. "issue was X, update to version Y or later to fix")

Comment: Thank you @KelvinSchoofs for the comment, I'm new in answering questions and when I solve any of my questions I'm trying to add my answer.